# Show that if $w$ is a zero of $P(z)$ (a complex polynomial) than $1/w$ is also

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $P(z) = 2z^4-5z^3+4z^2-5z+2.$

if $w$ is a zero of $P(z)$ show that $1/w$ is also a zero of that polynomial.

Comment: Do you mean $1/w$?

Comment: What denotes $$41/w4$$?

Comment: Surely you have tried something, no?

Comment: Sorry all, I fat-fingered my edit.

Comment: I tried setting w=rcis(θ) therefore w^(-1)=(1/r)cis(-θ) and then replacing it in the equation but couldn´t arrive at any conclusion, I also tried using the property that states that a complex polynomial with real coefficients has conjugated zeroes, so if w is a zero of P(z) then rcis(-θ) should also be a zero. Also tried decomposing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just note that $z^4P(\dfrac1z)=P(z)$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 0):

We must substitute $$w->\frac{1}{w}$$ in your equation:
$$\frac{2}{w^4}-\frac{5}{w^3}+\frac{4}{w^2}-\frac{5}{w}+2$$
and this must be zero if
$$2w^4-5w^3+4w^2-5w+2=0$$